# Change current tab name with script in ConEmu

Tags: command-line, conemu

I have a Powershell script that I launch from ConEmu, and I would like to be able to have this script change the name of the current tab (from where it was launched) so that I can see from which tab I launched the script.  I see that I could change the name of the tab using a GUIMacro Rename command, but it has to specify which tab by number.  Is there a way to pass the current tab number into my script so I can execute the GUIMacro rename command with the correct tab number?

Comment: Have you even tried it? `Rename` function does not require tab number. https://conemu.github.io/en/GuiMacro.html#Rename

Comment: Yes, sorry Maximus.  I saw a RenameTab in a previous question and didn't see just plain Rename.  It worked very well.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Maximus, for the obvious answer in the comments.

I added something like this to the end of my Powershell script and it works very well:

```
$tabName = "Thing1"
& "C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu\ConEmuC.exe" -GUIMacro Rename(0,"Stuff-$tabName")
```